# Exception has occurred. RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2) in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, exception

im trying to dynamically add new activitys with a "+"-Button.
The problem is, as soon as I save it and try to reopen it I get a
"Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2)".

The problem occurs only when I try to reopen it.

Thats my Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../utils/theme_utils.dart';
import '../models/goal.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class Checklist extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(Goal) onGoalSaved;
  final Goal? initialGoal;

  const Checklist({required this.onGoalSaved, this.initialGoal, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChecklistState createState() => _ChecklistState();
}

class _ChecklistState extends State<Checklist> {
  List<bool> checkBoxValues = [false, false];
  List<String> activityTexts = ["", ""];
  File? selectedImage;
  late TextEditingController titleController;
  late List<TextEditingController> activityControllers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize controllers
    titleController = TextEditingController();

    // Initialize controllers for activities
    activityControllers = List.generate(2, (index) => TextEditingController(text: activityTexts[index]));

    // Set controllers if an initial goal is provided
    if (widget.initialGoal != null) {
      final initialGoal = widget.initialGoal!;

      titleController.text = initialGoal.title;

      // Use the same list instance instead of creating a new one
      checkBoxValues = List.from(initialGoal.activities);
      activityTexts = initialGoal.activityTexts;
      selectedImage = initialGoal.imagePath.isNotEmpty ? File(initialGoal.imagePath) : null;

      // Set text for activity controllers
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        activityControllers[i].text = activityTexts[i];
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _pickImage() async {
    final imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    try {
      final pickedFile = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        setState(() {
          selectedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Fehler beim Bildauswählen: $e");
    }
  }

  void _createCircleDiagram() {
    final newGoal = Goal(
      title: titleController.text,
      imagePath: selectedImage?.path ?? "",
      activities: checkBoxValues,
      activityTexts: activityTexts,
    );

    widget.onGoalSaved(newGoal);

    Navigator.pop(context); // Zurück zum Homescreen
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    titleController.dispose();
    for (var controller in activityControllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Ziel"),
        backgroundColor: ThemeUtils.baseColor,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: () {
              _createCircleDiagram();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text(
                "Mein SMARTes Ziel",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: titleController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Dein Text hier...",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text(
                "Mein Glaube",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: _pickImage,
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  child: selectedImage != null
                      ? Image.file(selectedImage!)
                      : const Center(
                          child: Text("Bild auswählen"),
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text(
                "Aktivitäten",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                children: List.generate(checkBoxValues.length, (index) {
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      Checkbox(
                        value: checkBoxValues[index],
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            checkBoxValues[index] = value ?? false;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          child: TextField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                            maxLines: null,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                activityTexts[index] = value;
                              });
                            },
                            controller: activityControllers[index],
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Aktivität $index...",
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
            // Plus-Button für neue Aktivitäten hinzufügen
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  checkBoxValues.add(false);
                  activityTexts.add("");
                  activityControllers.add(TextEditingController());
                });
              },
              child: Text("Neue Aktivität hinzufügen"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And it appears right here:

```
controller: activityControllers[index],
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

## The Exception

> RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value:
> Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2)

Basically means the selected index is not in the range of the list. The numbers here "0..1: 2" indicate the list start with 0, ends with 1 and the selected index is 2.

In dart lists start at 0, which means square brackets selector with 2 would be the third item in the list.

### Example

```dart
final list = [1, 2, 3];

list[0]; // Should be 1
list[1]; // Should be 2
list[2]; // Should be 3;
list[3]; // Should throw RangeError 
// (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3)
```

---

## The fault in the code in the question

If the error is thrown at controller: `activityControllers[index]` it is using the index generated from `checkBoxValues.length`. The list range may mismatch if the `checkBoxValues` & `activityControllers` don't contain the same number of items.

The error seems to be caused by dynamically reassigning `List<bool> checkBoxValues` here

```dart
//... 
// Use the same list instance instead of creating a new one
checkBoxValues = List.from(initialGoal.activities);
//...
```

which does not match the items in the list here

```dart
// Set text for activity controllers
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  activityControllers[i].text = activityTexts[i];
}
```

Try making those 2 lists have the same number of items.

Or choose generate each widget by it's own length. Something like

```dart
List.generate(checkBoxValues.length, (index) {
//...
return Checkbox(
         value: checkBoxValues[index],
```

```dart
List.generate(activityControllers.length, (index) {
//...
return TextField(
         controller: activityControllers[index],
```